# Bash shell doesn't work properly (VSCode)

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code

I've started setting up VScode for python and I have a problem with the git bash shell that I've installed and already added to user settings. The terminal switched to bash but it doesn't look right and it won't work. It looks like this:

[image]

And as long as I know it should look like this:
[image]

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what your problem is exactly. Here is a link to [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_managing-multiple-terminals) that might help. Also, perhaps there is a typo in your first screenshot. `../Axmed/python'/..` when I assume it should be `../Axmed/python/..` without the **'**